# Using RxSwift, How To Enable UIButton Based on Valid Text?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

In RxSwift/RxCocoa 2.0.0- beta 3, I have a ViewModel with:

```
let someString = Variable("")

func isValidSomeString() -> Observable<Bool>  {

    if someString.value.characters.count == 0 {
        return just(false)
    }
    return just(true)
}
```

I have the someString bound already to a text field in the ViewController.

Whenever the someString (or perhaps the text field if that's a better way) changes, I want a button enabled based on if someString is valid.

I tried using the "Observable< Bool >", but started going down another path. I could do this in the ViewController:

```
    someViewModel.someString.subscribeNext { text -> Void in

        // could just someUIButton.enabled = someViewModel.isValidSomeString(text)

    }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Isn't there another way that is less verbose than the isValidSomeString(text) approach? We already have had nice success with a isValidLogin that returns Observable< Bool > which used combineLatest.

Comment: As a side note and using the example above, one can also just return the self.someString.map { !$0.isEmpty } in the isValidSomeString. In the View Controller, bind the someUIButton.rx_enabled to the someViewModel.isValidSomeString()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like [`Action`](https://github.com/ashfurrow/Action) is the perfect tool to use in this case. You'll want to create an `Action` in your ViewModel, let its `enabledIf` observable be the result of changes to the string, and connect this action to your `UIButton`. This way the button will be auto-enabled.

In your ViewModel, you'll need to add this:

```
var buttonAction: CocoaAction {
    let hasString = self.someString.map { !$0.isEmpty }
    return CocoaAction(enabledIf: hasString) {
        // do something when button tapped
        return empty()
    }
}
```

And when binding your ViewController to your ViewModel, you'll do:

```
myButton.rx_action = viewModel.buttonAction
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you just need to `map` your `someString` to `Obserable<Bool>` and then bind it to `rx_enabled` of `UIButton`
Something like this:

```
someViewModel.someString
             .asObservable()
             .map { (str) -> Bool in
                 return someViewModel.isValidSomeString(text)
             }
            .bindTo(someUIButton.rx_enabled)
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

but I think it whould be simpler if you would  have `Variable<Bool>` in your viewmodel kind of

```
struct ViewModel {
....
    canLogIn = Variable(false)
}
```

In this case you will be able bind it to `rx_enabled` like this:

```
  let userNameValidation = loginTextField
     .rx_text
     .map({!$0.isEmpty})
     .shareReplay(1)

  let passwordValidation = passwordTextField
     .rx_text
     .map({!$0.isEmpty})
     .shareReplay(1)

  let loginEnabled = combineLatest(userNameValidation, passWordValidation) { (username, password) in
     return username && password
  }

  loginEnabled
     .bindTo(loginViewModel.canlogIn)
     .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

  loginViewModel.canlogIn
         .bindTo(loginButton.rx_enabled)
         .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```